Can we find a nonzero left integral in a Frobenius algebra?
Suppose that $A$ is a Frobenius algebra over a field $K$ of characteristic zero with the  nondegenerate bilinear form $(\;,\,) : A \times A \rightarrow K$ satisfying the associative property $(ab,c)=(a,bc)$. We define a left integral in $A$ as an element $L \in A$ which satisfies $aL=\epsilon(a)L$ where $\epsilon : A \rightarrow K$ is an algebra homomorphism. What is an example of a left integral in $A$?

For an example, take $A = kG$ where $G$ is a finite group and $k$ a field of characteristic 0.  The form is defined by bilinear extension of $(g, h) = 1$ if $gh=e$ (the identity in $G$) and 0 otherwise, for $g, h \in G$.  Since $(gh)k = g(hk)$, this is associative.  The augmentation $\epsilon : kG \to k$ is the linear map such that $\epsilon(g)=1$ for any $g \in G$.
Then put $L = \sum_{g \in G}g \neq 0$ so that for any $g \in G$ we have $gL = L$. For $a=\sum a_g g \in kG$ we then have $aL = \left(\sum_g a_g\right)L = \epsilon(a)L$.

Let $A=\mathbb{C}\oplus M_2(\mathbb{C})$ over $K=\mathbb{C}$. Let the bilinear form be the trace:
$$\operatorname{Tr}((x,a),(y,b))=xy+\operatorname{Tr}(ab)\qquad (x,y\in\mathbb{C},\,a,b\in M_2(\mathbb{C})).$$
Let, for $x\in \mathbb{C}$ and $a\in M_2(\mathbb{C})$, $\varepsilon(x,a)=x$ then a left integral is given by $L=(1,0)$ as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(x,a)L=(x,a)(1,0)=(x,0)=x(1,0)=\varepsilon(x,a)L
\end{aligned}$$
